# How did Dr. Linda come clean?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, lucifer

In the Lucifer episode 2x17 we learn that:

> Dr. Linda is suspended because she has helped Lucifer from escaping the mental hospital. The situation gets worse when Lucifer tells the chair of the ethics review board that he had sex with her.

However in the episode 3x1:

> We see she is back at work consulting Lucifer.

Now I want to ask how she came clean from that. The situation looked desperate. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Maze fixed it for her

Maze told Linda:

> No, it is not your fault. It is Lucifer's fault.
>
> It's always Lucifer's fault.
>
> First, I find out he's ditching me to go to Heaven, and now he's hurting you.
>
> Look, I'm gonna fix this, Linda.
>
> And then him and I are gonna have a little talk.

**Later on we see Maze visit the review board chair’s office. She pushes him inside and closes the door.**

Comment: Yes I remember the scene. Is this the only hint that we get from the show? Did she simply force him to drop the case out of the screen?

Comment: Basically yes...she either threatened him or *persuaded* him another way. :)

Comment: She is MAZE. she can do anything

Comment: This answer is so unsatisfying.. apart from that they did not even mention it anymore. We could at least get a comment from Linda about what happened and how the accusations were dropped